# How to get row count of audit table using hibernate envers

Tags: hibernate, projection, hibernate-envers, audit-tables

In audit table, there is not such a Criteria that we could use `Criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount())` to get the row count of the query.

We could use AuditQuery to do similar things. But I couldn't find how to set projections in this case. There is also a `setProjection` method for AuditQuery, but it takes `AuditProjection` as parameter. Is there a similar thing that I could `setProjection(rowCount)`?

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/envers/api-new/org/hibernate/envers/query/projection/class-use/AuditProjection.html `AuditProperty.count()`?

Comment: It is possible to do a count on one field, but that is not I want. I want a row count for the final result. The should return the same result as AuditQuery.getResultList().size().

Answer (score 12):

You can do a count on a given field, e.g.:

```
getAuditReader().createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(SomeEntity.class, false, true)
    .addProjection(AuditEntity.id().count()).getSingleResult()
```

Or you can count the revision numbers:

```
getAuditReader().createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(SomeEntity.class, false, true)
    .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().count()).getSingleResult()
```

Comment: Yes, we could get a count on a given field by using the AuditProperty.count(). But, still, this is not give me the row count the entire query result.

Comment: If you add a count projection to an otherwise normal query, you should get what you need, no?

Comment: Hi Adam, addProjection(AuditEntity.id().count("id")).getSingleResult()  gave me the correct count. At first, I thought this only gave me the count for the original entity ids.